# App Launched from Safari Displays: Do you want to allow this page to open "(null)"?

Tags: objective-c, macos, go

I am writing a Mac OS app in Go/Objective-C. Suffice it to say, I am not using Xcode and have assembled the application bundle by hand. Here is what it's filesystem hierarchy looks like

```
${APPNAME}.app
  Contents
    MacOS
      ${APPNAME} (binary)
  Resources
    Base.lproj
      InfoPlist.strings (text)
  Info.plist (text)
```

The bundle launches fine. Application works as expected. I have a CFBundleURLTypes dictionary in my Plist file which defines a URL scheme for my application.

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>${APPNAME}</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>zzz</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

(Note: `${APPNAME}` is something like "MyApp." It is not a Java-style, reverse DNS name string.)

When I click on a link in Safari that uses the zzz:// scheme, I get a message that says:

```
Do you want to allow this page to open "(null)"?
```

Why is that? I have defined my application name in both the Info.plist file and in the InfoPlist.strings file.

The InfoPlist.strings file simply contains this:

```
CFBundleName = "My Wonderful Application"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There apparently was some sort of caching mechanism happening. When deployed to another Mac system we managed to procure, which never had the software in question installed on it, this problem did not occur.

Note: The previous system which behaved erroneously had, at the beginning of each test, the software *completely* removed from it. Finder, Safari or some other Apple software must have secretly cached the app name as "(null)".

Answer: Install it on a new Mac machine, or completely restore (with no backup) the machine you are testing with.