# How to Mitigate Safari Warning "Do you want to allow this page to open XYZ"

Tags: macos, safari

I am developing an application in Objective-C and Go. So far, everything is working out quite well - except for a few [hiccups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41603006/app-launched-from-safari-displays-do-you-want-to-allow-this-page-to-open-null).

What I want to know is: Is it possible to mitigate the warning Safari gives me when clicking on a link, which opens an installed application with a custom URL scheme?

My application has a custom scheme. Let's say it is XYZ. When I click on a link, such as

```
xyz://dosomething?cool=yes+please
```

I get the warning

```
Do you want to allow this page to open XYZ?
```

Any way to not have this prompt come up every time?

Comment: Just came across this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41684417/901334

Comment: Does not prevent the prompt from coming up each time. Looks like this is new Safari behavior and something we have to live with.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's a new security policy of Safari (in 10.12.2+), at the moment there is no way to go around it. Maybe in a future Safari update they'll add an option to "Always allow" or a preference setting to disable it.

If you [google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=safari%20do%20you%20want%20to%20allow%20this%20page%20to%20open) you'll find tons of people with this problem since using URL schemes to launch external apps is a quite common approach... Very popular applications like Transmission use it.

Comment: Exactly. Customers need to realize that Apple owns these products and will make changes to it that impacts how our software is deployed. There currently exists no workaround.

Comment: As of Safari 17 (released Sept 2023) The "Always Allow" option is now available in the dialog.

Comment: Is there anyway to reset this option, i.e., to go back to always asking after choosing "Always Allow"?

Answer (score -1):

### The only solution : use chromium based browser instead :

1. Close the chromium based browser you choose if it's open
2. Type this command in a terminal : defaults write $BUNDLE_ID ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox -bool TRUE

In the above command, replace $BUNDLE_ID by the bundle ID of the browser you choose :

- com.google.Chrome
- org.chromium.Chromium
- com.brave.Browser
- ...

3. Relaunch your chromium based browser, click the link with the protocole that handles your app
4. In the dialog box, click the "Always allow ..." option before clicking the [Open ...] button
5. That's it ... You'll get rid of the question all next times you click on your links